# Dependencies that must be done away with for using CDN

Tags: asp.net, performance, web, cdn

I wanted to know that, is there some special requirement for a website to make use of CDN ?

i mean is there some special scheme(or atleast considerations) on which your website must be build right from the start to make use of CDN (Content delivery network).

is there anything that can stop a website from making use of CDN, for example the way it references the content files, static file paths or any other thing conceivable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

You have two kinds of CDN services:

- Services like AWS Cloudfront that require you to upload the files in some special place that they read from (eg. AWS S3) - In this case you need have a step in your build process to correctly upload the files and handle the addresses somehow inside your application
- Services like Akamai that just need you to change and tweak your DNS records so they will serve the request to your users instead of you - In this case you would have two domains (image.you.com and image2.you.com) and have the image.you.com pointing to Akamai and image2.you.com pointing to the original source of the file. Whenever a user requested an image in Akamai, they would come to you through the "back door", fetch it and starting serving that file always.

If you use the second approach it's really simple to have a CDN supporting your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of concerns when dealing with CDN solutions.

The first one is that a CDN can't serve a dynamic page - i.e. a page that is unique to every user. Typically, that includes PHP, ASPX, JSP, RubyOnRails etc. - so if you're hoping to support lots of users for a dynamic site, you have to come up with another solution. Some CDN providers support "Edge Side Includes" - this allows you to glue dynamic pages together with cached content on the CDN, but this creates quite a complex application.

Of course, even on a dynamic application, a CDN can still serve static files - images, stylesheets, javascript files, videos etc.

@Tucaz explains the two major options here (actually, Akamai also provides a "filestore" CDN option). If you select the second option - effectively, the CDN becomes a caching reverse proxy in front of your website - it makes sense to [tweak the cache headers on your HTTP server](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/), and tell the CDN to honour those. Make sure you set your .ASPX files to not cache!